# TNS:listener times out every 2 hours on VPN

Tags: oracle, vpn, tns

I have a locally installed Oracle XE instance I use, but it times out every 2 hours on our corporate VPN. It's like clockwork, 2 hours after connecting I get:

```
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

If I reconnect the VPN it starts working again, 2 more hours then reconnect. Any way to avoid this? Any way even to refresh it without reconnecting the VPN, as that in itself is a total pain.

**Update**

listener.ora looks like:

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Oracle\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <FQDN>)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Where  is the fully qualified domain name of my machine.

Comment: What does your listener.ora look like?  Are you connecting locally?  Or from clients on other machines?

Comment: All local connections. Updated in main comment for listener.ora

Comment: What is FQDN?  Fully qualified domain name?  How is domain name resolution being done in your environment?  Any chance IP addresses leases only last 2 hours?  If everything is local, I’d change the listener and tnsnames file (assuming that’s what you’re using) to specify localhost instead

Comment: Tried with localhost in both files. 2 hours on VPN, then stops working.